# Python Multiprocessing - Why are my processes are not returning/finishing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to parallelize one of my long running tasks. For some reason, it just wont finish and is hanging forever.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class PartitionedResult(object):
    index = 0
    P = []
    def __init__(self, index, P):
        self.index = index
        self.P = P        


def longRunningTask(index, output):
    P = []
    for i in range (0, 1000):        
        print(i)
        P.append(i)

    print("I'm done!")
    output.put(PartitionedResult(index, P))
    return

def main():
    output = mp.Queue()
    processes = [mp.Process(target=longRunningTask, args=(x,output,)) for x in range(4)]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    results = [output.get() for p in processes]
    print("This never shows up")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It is printing the numbers 0-999 for every of the 4 proccesses and it is even reaching the "I'm done!" line, but it just wont get to the `results = [output.get() for p in processes]` line

If I reduce the range of the `for` loop to let's say `range(0,50)`, it suddenly works.

What's the problem here?

Edit: I'm using Python 3.4 on Windows 10, I tried it on 2 different computers and with the pycache deleted.

Comment: Can't reproduce. The posted code worked for me.

Comment: Aw! that's strange. I copied the code into a new file and I'm still having the same problem. I restarted my PC twice. Which version of python are you running? I'm on python 3.4 on windows

Comment: I'm python 3.4 on linux mint 17.3.

Comment: I meanwhile tested it on a second computer with the same result --> it still doesn't work for me. I also deleted the python cache.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are calling `join()` on all the processes before you're `get()`ing the results. When a Queue's buffer fills up, it can block when the data is flushed to the underlying pipe. If you `join()` a process blocked that way from your consumer process you have a deadlock because the process can only exit after all data has been written.

Move the call to join to the end of your `main()` then it should work:

```
def main():
    output = mp.Queue()
    processes = [mp.Process(target=longRunningTask, args=(x,output,)) for x in range(4)]

    for p in processes:
        p.start()  

    results = [output.get() for p in processes]
    print("This never shows up")

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Comment: What if I don't use a Queue - what then?

Comment: Your solution hangs by the way... ;/

Answer (score 1):

If a process appears hung or deadlocked it can be useful to be able to kill it forcibly. Calling terminate() on a process object kills the child process. Basic example:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def slow_worker():
print 'Starting worker'
time.sleep(0.1)
print 'Finished worker'

if __name__ == '__main__':
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=slow_worker)
print 'BEFORE:', p, p.is_alive()

p.start()
print 'DURING:', p, p.is_alive()

p.terminate()
print 'TERMINATED:', p, p.is_alive()
```

Comment: How can this work if we don't know if the process hangs or not?

Comment: This example prints that the process is still alive at the end.  However, if I add time.sleep(0.001) between p.terminate() and the last print statement, then the script prints that the process is not alive.  Do I have a race condition when terminating?  I'm running in the Spyder console on a Windows platform